# Onload Javascript/jQuery Not Working In HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Java script in Html is as follows.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {  
    var found = {{.found}}
    window.alert("hiiii");
    if (foundRecords==true) {
       document.getElementById("abc").style.display = "block";
    }
    return    
});
```

This should get loaded during the time of html loading. But it's not at all loading. I didn't find anything wrong in this simple peace of code.

Comment: What is `{{.found}}`? Do you get any error in `console`?

Comment: Plus, `foundRecords` can't be true, as it's not defined.

Comment: @X.L.Ant, sorry its found as i have inintialized it at top...it is found in my script...but no error and no output of that function

Comment: I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`. The line `var found = {{.found}}` should probably be `var found = {'.found'};` if you want to select the CSS class `found`. And as mentioned before `foundRecords` is not declared or is eventually a global variable, but we can't guess that.

Comment: And you are missing `;` as line end. It is really a bad style.

Comment: Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.    this error i am getting in console

Comment: and alert also not working...

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get elements with class found {{.found}}

```
window.onload = function()
{
   var found = document.getElementsByClassName("found");
   if (found) {
       document.getElementById("abc").style.display = "block";
    }

}
```

Comment: nope, found is not an style or class.. its an boolean variable i am getting from beego cotroller....and more over the control itself is not going inside this function

Comment: So you must define and initialize var  foundRecords , in your code foundRecords is undefined variable @VijayKumar

Comment: yes i do have initialized... but i am saying that even alert which is outside if condition also not executing which means control is not going inside document.ready

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery to load that function it will take a slight change:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // get the class found and assign it to a variable found
    var found = $('.found') // it was {{.found}} producing an error
    window.alert("hiiii");
    // where does foundRecords come from? it is up to you to clear this
    if ( foundRecords == true ) {
       document.getElementById("abc").style.display = "block";
    }
    // what is the return good for?
    // it would be better to return true or false
    // or leave it away
    return;
});
```

Check the jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bx0e18L4/

Now it alerts the message, but still has the problem with the variable `foundRecords`. Take care for that.

EDIT:

According to your comments above the variable `foundRecords` should be `found`, so the critical line should be:

```
if ( found == true ) { // processing }
```